# Trying to import a big csv in Rails stops after about 3000 lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

The code below doesn't produce an error, instead after about 2800 row it just stops and tailing the log just shows the last added row. I have a hunch it runs out of memory but it shouldn't vm has 2GB of ram and 1GB swap. Also that CSV.foreach should be way more efficient on this file size.

The file is uploaded via a web interface and has about 2MB.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :company

  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
     
      sale_hash = row.to_hash
      sale = Sale.where(id: sale_hash["id"], date: sale_hash["date"].to_datetime)
        
      if sale.count == 1
        sale.first.update_attributes(sale_hash)
      else
        Sale.create!(sale_hash)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How long before it times out?

Comment: @RyanBigg I think it is a timeout... about 30s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be timing out. You can use gems such as `delayed_job` or `resque` to process it as a background process.

Comment: You're right! After 30 seconds the session was timing out. Had to store it locally and process it in the background.